# Oracle IIg Windows 64 Install

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g

Tryine to do local install of Oracle 11g 64 on Win 7, everything goes fine but when I try to launch enterprise manager at https://localhost:1158/em I get a security certificate error. Where in the installation instructions was the thing I missed that would have prevented this? Google was no help. I'm getting error message burnout.

Answer (score 1):

The certificate error is because the SSL certificate was not signed.
This is expected on a new install.

Generally for you can ignore this error and press continue or accept in the browser.